# Android - how to check if the device is in the same wifi

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I want to write a program that wants to restrict location updates when the device is in the same wifi network. How would I go about doing that? How do I check if the device is in the same wifi network as earlier?

Comment: Got the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329682/unable-to-listen-to-android-wifi-managers-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()` will give you information about current Wifi network.