# responding to wifi availability

Tags: android

how exactly should I configure my broadcast receiver to make my app respond to changes in the wifi availability. I do not really care about reacting to it when the app is not running though.

What I am trying to accomplish here is that as the app is running I need to keep the local DB in synch with a copy on the server. If for whatever reason I lost my connection I need to know when it makes sense to try to re connect.

Comment: You might want to clarify a bit about what you mean by "changes in the wifi availability".

Comment: I mean whether I can or cannot access a certain web site (service)

Comment: Um, that did not particularly clarify matters. :-) Are you worried about the device going in and out of airplane mode? The user enabling and disabling WiFi? The user adding/removing access points? The user moving into/out of range of an access point? Something else?

Comment: any of the above. May be with the exception for airplane mode. In other words if for whatever reason I lost my connection to the server I want to know when it makes sense to try to re-connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't care about it when the app is not running I suggest you register your receiver in code, rather then putting it in the manifest...

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter( WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION );
context.registerReceiver( wifiStateRec, filter);
WifiManager wifim = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService( Context.WIFI_SERVICE );
state = wifim.getWifiState();    // get initial state
```

And then call unregisterReceiver() when you are finished with it.

Your receiver could look like this:

```
protected BroadcastReceiver wifiStateRec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        assertTrue( WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equalsIgnoreCase( intent.getAction() ) );

        state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,-1);
        String msg;
        switch(state)   {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            msg = "it is disabled";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            msg = "it is enabled";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
            msg = "it is switching off";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
            msg="wifi is getting enabled";
            break;
        default:
            msg="not working properly";
            break;
        }
        Log.i(CTAG, "Wifi state = " + msg );
    }
};
```

Some of the code in this function originally came from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329682/unable-to-listen-to-android-wi-fi-managers-state).