# Service to keep checking WIFI to turn ON all the time on android using service

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am writing a service with WifiManager class to detect if wifi is turned OFF or turned ON. If  turned OFF my code turns it ON on startService. Now I have a usecase in which I manually turn OFF the wifi when the service is already running. I would like the service to keep checking if the Wifi is turned ON. If not turn it ON. My code is as follows.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    // Check for wifi is disabled
    if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false){
        // If wifi disabled then enable it
        mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);    
    }
    wi = mainWifi.getConnectionInfo();
    Toast.makeText(this,"network "+wi.getSSID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to make this work. What I see now is what ever I put in the onStartCommand executes only once when the service is started. But I want to keep this running all the time to check and later perform some operation to broadcast. I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

more convenient than periodically checking connection info is to register a `BroadcastReceiver` on `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED`, e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329682/unable-to-listen-to-android-wi-fi-managers-state), on wifi off you could start your service from receiver

Comment: I implemented the above using thread. It is working. Thanks though I will try to use BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    running = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    Runnable r = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running){
            if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false){
                // If wifi disabled then enable it
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", 
                //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);    
            }
            wi = mainWifi.getConnectionInfo();
            Log.i("wificheckthread","Service running"+wi.getSSID());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    return START_STICKY;

}
```

This will keep the thread running for every minute. Please post if someone has better answer