# App crashing while trying to display the IP Address -- permissions?

Tags: android

When I call the method below, my application crashes. In my `AndroidManifest.xml`, the pplication has permission to access wifi state.

```
public void show(View view) throws UnknownHostException {    
    WifiManager wm =
        (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (!wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

    int ip = wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
    String s = Integer.toString(ip);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_name);
    et.setText("" + ip);
}
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10170 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
    at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getConnectionInfo(IWifiManager.java:1125)
    at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getConnectionInfo(WifiManager.java:1315)
    at com.example.shankey.chatoz.MainActivity.show(MainActivity.java:28)
    ... 11 more⁠⁠⁠⁠
```

Please suggest a method to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your error log

Comment: link to my error log : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gZHzu1Qyt66hPmUevAxr9xMrHc31ykU-KrWl1jDky0E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing on above version of lollipop ?? You have to ask for permission explicitly in code in the show() method.

or check this link may be it will helpfull for you ..

[Unable to listen to android wi-fi manager's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329682/unable-to-listen-to-android-wi-fi-managers-state)

Comment: yea got it (y) had used "user permission instead of uses permission " realised it by your post ... thanks for it (y)

Comment: now the issue is the ip which is displayed is 151103680 where as the ip must have been something lyk 19216819 ...